# How to get the last messages sent to me at firebase Messages node?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

the first children is my UID code and it is easy to get it , the second children is the sender UID and I can't get it 
the third children is a unique key 
I just want to retrieve the last message for every sender

this is my code

```
 String my_Id = currentuser.getUid();
    dataQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages").child(my_Id);
    dataQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot getalldata, String s) {

            Map<String,Object> sender = (Map<String,Object>) getalldata.getValue());

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : sender.entrySet()){

                Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
                String sender_UID = entry.getKey(); 
                // I can't get UID of the sender so I can't get last message

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("szx", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

the problem is that I can't get UID of the sender so I can't get messages
Is there any way to get Last messages without need to know the sender UID ?
If it is impossible , then How can I get every UID of each sender and get last messages ?

[image: this is message node]

Answer (score 0):

In your database you have:

```
Messages
 idthatyoucanget
    senderid
        randomid
```

to get the id, that you are unable to get try this:

```
 String my_Id = currentuser.getUid();
dataQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages").child(my_Id);
dataQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot getalldata, String s) {

       String ids=getalldata.getKey();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("szx", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
    });
```

Since you are using onchildadded you do not need to iterate to be able to get the sender id.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. then How can I get last messages ? can you complete your answer ?

Comment: for that you need to iterate, `for(DataSnasphot datas: getalldata.getChildren()){  String messages=datas.child("message").getValue().toString()`